# StringIndexOutofBoundsException when trying to setBackgroundColor using a variable inside an Adapter, why?

Tags: android, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following binding method:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: bomViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val color=ListTheColorTone[position].color
  holder.cardBlack.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color!!))
}
```

When invoked I get the following error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
  at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
  at com.example.wallpaperapp.Adapter.colortoneAdapter.onBindViewHolder(colortoneAdapter.kt:33)
  at com.example.wallpaperapp.Adapter.colortoneAdapter.onBindViewHolder(colortoneAdapter.kt:15)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6012)
```

This doesn't happen when I manually insert the String inside the `parseColor`, for example `parseColor("#ffffff");` works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image: error]

Comment: `color` is an empty string, `""`. the parse method fails to find such a color (for obvious reasons). you can easily confirm that by using `println("Color is: $color")` (or by using your debugger)

Answer (score 1):

The [`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is an unchecked exception that occurs when an attempt is made to access the character of a string at an index which is either negative or greater than the length of the string.

> Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of the string. For some methods such as the charAt method, this exception also is thrown when the index is equal to the size of the string.

So something somewhere is trying to access a character at an index that is either negative or greater than the length of the string.
If we look at the stacktrace we can see that the exception is thrown from the `Color.parseColor` method:

```kotlin
// TIP: Length of 0 means an empty string!
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
  at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
  // The stack trace is guiding us to line 33!
  at com.example.wallpaperapp.Adapter.colortoneAdapter.onBindViewHolder(colortoneAdapter.kt:33)
  at com.example.wallpaperapp.Adapter.colortoneAdapter.onBindViewHolder(colortoneAdapter.kt:15)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6012)
```

Therefore, `Color.parseColor` is getting an empty (`""`) String as an argument, We can see color is coming from a collection named `ListTheColorTone`:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: bomViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val color=ListTheColorTone[position].color // <= This returns an empty String
  
  holder.cardBlack.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color!!)) // <= This is the line where the exception is thrown
}
```

#### What does this mean to us?

The `ListTheColorTone` collection is perhaps missing an element at the `position` that is passed. Or some other logic in your application is incorrect. As @Zabuzard advised, try printing the value of `position` (or perhaps the contents of the collection) to understand what's going wrong:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: bomViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val color=ListTheColorTone[position].color // <= This returns an empty string

  println("position: $position")
  println("ListTheColorTone: ${ListTheColorTone.toList()}")
  println("color: $color")

  holder.cardBlack.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color!!)) // <= This is the line where the exception is thrown
}
```

Or even better, try adding a breakpoint at the line where the exception is thrown and check the value of `position` and `ListTheColorTone.size`. Here are some resources to get you started:

- [Tutorial: Debug your first Kotlin application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-your-first-kotlin-application.html)
- [Android - Debug with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-debugging-with-breakpoints#0)